# Are there such things as children scenarios in Behat?

Tags: php, behat, gherkin

I'm working on some testing that has some pretty extensive submission forms with nested forms. As such, we have a lot of sections that repeat based on the content. For example, User Information. Currently in Behat, I'm creating everything in my Feature, and copy/pasting the user info steps. I'm using Behat 3.x, and didn't want to try to create the chaining issue they removed from 2.5.

With that said, is there a better way to do this? I've been wondering about creating child blocks of code, but I'm not sure how that'd work since Behat will try to run all the features in a directory unless you call them individually (which I'm not opposed to). From Googling this issue, I don't believe I'm the first one to see the value of chaining steps while also understanding the potential complications associated with it. I just want to know if there's a better way of doing this in a more Behat method.

I can certainly appreciate the simplicity of Gherkin, and I'd like to be able to keep my tests human readable for other eyes. Chaining, or building custom functions in my FeatureContext.php that make the calls themselves in my eyes takes away from the point of having something like Gherkin, but at the same time, I'd really want a better way of defining multiple steps at a time. Is there a best practices for this particular issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try answering using the example given: You could write a User Information factory for testing the scenarios that require User Information to be pre-populated before beginning the scenario at hand. I'm assuming you have existing tests for this feature that test the basic functionality of adding that user information already, the other tests don't need to be chained to those tests in a way that aggregates changes. Hopefully I'm understanding your question in the way you intended.